# Puma 2.10.1 not restarting

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, puma

I have a Puma server in production running a Rails 4 API in an Amazon AWS Ubuntu machine. I just upload some code and made a bundle install. Everything looked good. However, the moment I tried to restart the server it doesn´t restart anymore.

The script looks good but the process doesn´t restart. I don´t see any error log:

> Puma starting in single mode...
>   * Version 2.10.1 (ruby 2.1.2-p95), codename: Robots on Comets
>   * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
>   * Environment: production
>   * Daemonizing...

I also have a test environment in same `Amazon` instance. I deployed there, made tests, run bundle install and restart before going live and everything went OK. I can restart that instance without problems.

I guess it´s not related, but I see this error message when log in to my Ubuntu instance:

> *** /dev/xvda1 should be checked for errors ***
>
> *** System restart required ***

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was crazy. For some strange reason I don´t understand I had a somehow corrupted controller with wrong syntax, like:

```
params.require(:mmk_resource).permit(:default_checkout_time, :string{20},, :calculate_agency_discount_without_vat, :decimal{4-2},, :taxable_amount, :decimal{10-2},, :tax_rate, :decimal{4-2},, :generic_resource_type_name, :string{100},, :default_checkin_day, :string{10},, :code_id, :integer,, :cg_id, :integer,, :company_id, :integer,, :transit_log, :string{100},, :default_cleaning_cost, :decimal{6-2})
```

I don´t know why this happened. But this was the root cause of the problem. After fixing this, the server restarted without problems again.

Comment: I've added some code formatting here, which reveals this code is all on one line. Is it really written like that? `:=)`